# Can Non-Continuous functions still be vectors within a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right", there is section of examples of subspaces. There is  a sentence that goes:

*The set of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$ is a subspace of $\mathbf{R}^{[0,1]}$*

I am having trouble trying to make sense of the description even before proving if that set is a subpace.

Based on these question asked on the forums: [What is $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$ as a vector space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592249/what-is-mathbb-r-mathbb-r-as-a-vector-space)

[What does the vector space R^[0,1] mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2596832/what-does-the-vector-space-r0-1-mean)

$\mathbf{R}^{[0,1]}$ corresponds to the set of functions in the interval [0,1], so a vector $f \in \mathbf{R}^{[0,1]}$ could be seen as an infinitely uncountable tuple where $(f(x_0), f(x_1), ....), x_i \in [0, 1], f(x_i) \in \mathbf{R} $

My question is, if a function f is not continuous in $[0,1]$, can it still an element of $\mathbf{R}^{[0,1]}$ ? For example, f(x) = ln(x)? If a function is not continous in 0 for example, then the tuple that represents ln(x) as a vector would have one less element than, for example, $f(x) = x^2$ ?

Comment: An element of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ is a function defined on $[0,1]$ that takes on real values. $\ln(x)$ is not in this set because it is not defined at $0$. You can have non-continuous functions in $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ though, for example the function $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in [0, 1/2]$ and $f(x) = -1$ for $x \in [1/2, 1]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions in ${\mathbb R}^{[0,1]}$ all have domain $[0,1]$, so $\ln(x)$ isn't in there. On the other hand that fact doesn't really have anything to do with continuity. The function $f:[0,1]\to {\mathbb R}$ defined by
$$
   f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x\in{\mathbb R} \setminus {\mathbb Q} \\ 1 & x\in {\mathbb Q} \end{cases}
$$
does belong to ${\mathbb R}^{[0,1]}$, even though it is (very) discontinuous. The only requirement for being in ${\mathbb R}^{[0,1]}$ is that you are a function with domain $[0,1]$ whose values are real numbers.

Comment: Ahh I see, so Q is just any subset. Thank you! I was wrongly assuming that functions output could not be repeated. Thank you for the explanation